# Definition of a projection on a normed space? Banach space?

Tags: normed-spaces

Given a vector space $V$, a projection $V\to V$ is an idempotent linear map.

For a normed space do we require anything else of the definition like continuity?  Is the image required to be closed in the case of Banach spaces?

I'm having difficulties tabulating the requirements in different settings and only going from what I vaguely recall.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd say it depends on context, but generally, talking about projections on a Banach space, including the unbounded ones without saying so explicitly seems perverse to me. I suppose you realize that the image of a bounded (continuous) projection is automatically closed, right?

Comment: "Bounded idempotent linear operator" is the most common definition on a normed space, I think. Which should not stop you from using a different notion if need be.

Comment: Hmm, am I the only one remembering "Let $P$ be a continuous projection ..."?